# How can use reflection to get the property names and values from a POJO?

Tags: java, json, generics, reflection

So I'm writing an "POJO to JSON" converter.  I want to be able to pass in a `List<T>` object and convert to JSON.

Hopefully this will make sense

```
/**
 *
     * NOT COMPLETE!!!  OBVIOUSLY!!!
 */
public abstract class Jsonator<T> implements Serializable {

    private Class<T> entityClass;
    private JSONObject json;
    private JSONArray jsonArray;

    public Jsonator(Class<T> entityClass) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }

    public void convert(List<T> paObjectList) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
        json = new JSONObject();
        jsonArray = new JSONArray();

        try {

            for (Object obj : paObjectList) {
                JSONObject objJson = new JSONObject();

                Class<?> kls = obj.getClass();

                Field[] fields = kls.getFields();
                for (Field field : fields) {
                    objJson.put(field.getName(), (T) field.get(obj));
                }

                jsonArray.add(objJson);
            }

            json.put("results", jsonArray);

        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
        }
    }

    public String error() {
        return "ERROR";
    }

    public String results() {
        if (json != null) {
            return json.toJSONString();
        }

        return "[]";
    }
}
```

When I get to the `Object obj` section, my `obj` is correct.  I can debug it and see the name and value of the class.

Let's say that class is this:

```
public class User {
    private firstName;
    private lastName;

    ... getters....setters....etc...

}
```

So that now, `obj` is a Site.
OK, I then try to get the field names (firstName, lastName) but the fields object is empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

**EDIT**

I got it to work!  This is not finished code, but it's doing exactly what I want for now.
I've read that Google and Jackson will do this too.  If someone can provide a good link on how to selectively pick properties from a POJO, then I'm all ears.

Or better yet, I'd like to know **WHY** I shouldn't be doing this, this way?

Thanks!

**Jsonator (NOT FINISHED)**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.List;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

/**
 *
 * @author Cecil.Meeks
 */
public abstract class Jsonator<T> implements Serializable {

    private Class<T> entityClass;
    private JSONObject json;
    private JSONArray jsonArray;

    public Jsonator(Class<T> entityClass) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }

    public void convert(List<T> paObjectList) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
        json = new JSONObject();
        jsonArray = new JSONArray();

        try {

            for (Object obj : paObjectList) {
                JSONObject objJson = new JSONObject();

                Class<?> kls = obj.getClass();

                Field[] fields = kls.getDeclaredFields();
                for (Field field : fields) {
                    field.setAccessible(true);
                    objJson.put(field.getName(), field.get(obj));
                }

                jsonArray.add(objJson);
            }

            json.put("results", jsonArray);

        }
        catch (SecurityException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String error() {
        return "ERROR";
    }

    public String results() {
        if (json != null) {
            return json.toJSONString();
        }

        return "[]";
    }
}
```

**Site Class**

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Sites")
public class Site implements Serializable {

    private String siteKey;
    private String site;
    private String siteType;
    private String address1;
    private String address2;
    private String city;
    private String zipCode;
    private String createdBy;
    private String glCode;

    public Site() {
    }

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "guid", parameters = {})
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
    public String getSiteKey() {
        return siteKey;
    }

    public void setSiteKey(String siteKey) {
        this.siteKey = siteKey;
    }

    @Column(name = "Site", unique = true, length = 125, nullable = false)
    public String getSite() {
        return site;
    }

    public void setSite(String site) {
        this.site = site;
    }

    @Column(name = "SiteType", unique = false, length = 8, nullable = true)
    public String getSiteType() {
        return siteType;
    }

    public void setSiteType(String siteType) {
        this.siteType = siteType;
    }

    @Column(name = "Address1", unique = false, length = 125, nullable = true)
    public String getAddress1() {
        return address1;
    }

    public void setAddress1(String address1) {
        this.address1 = address1;
    }

    @Column(name = "Address2", unique = false, length = 125, nullable = true)
    public String getAddress2() {
        return address2;
    }

    public void setAddress2(String address2) {
        this.address2 = address2;
    }

    @Column(name = "City", unique = false, length = 125, nullable = true)
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    @Column(name = "ZipCode", unique = false, length = 50, nullable = true)
    public String getZipCode() {
        return zipCode;
    }

    public void setZipCode(String zipCode) {
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
    }

    @Column(name = "CreatedBy", unique = false, length = 125, nullable = true)
    public String getCreatedBy() {
        return createdBy;
    }

    public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

    @Column(name = "GLCode", unique = false, length = 11, nullable = true)
    public String getGlCode() {
        return glCode;
    }

    public void setGlCode(String glCode) {
        this.glCode = glCode;
    }


}
```

**EXAMPLE**

```
public class SiteJsonator extends Jsonator<Site> {

    public SiteJsonator() {
        super(Site.class);
    }

}

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/sites")
public class SitesController {

    @Autowired
    private SiteService siteService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public String index(ModelMap map) {

        SiteJsonator list  = new SiteJsonator();;
        try {
            list.convert(siteService.getAll());
            return list.results();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            return list.error();
        } 
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

Here is the better `Jsonator` for those interested:

https://gist.github.com/3893242

You can pass in an "exclude" String[] and it will not include those.  Plus, it has a standard "results, message, etc" that we like to pass back in our AJAX requests.  Good for ExtJS.

Comment: Can you provide a *real* example?  What is the `Site` object?

Comment: Are you coding this for fun? If not, there are many libraries out there (e.g. [google-gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)) that can do this for you. Side note: *Jsonator* is an excellent name :-)

Comment: This is not a real 'answer' to your question but you could possibly try this: http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/  which already converts JSON <-> Objects.

Comment: @DuncanJones well, I only program for fun.  :-)  But seriously, we have a procedure where we query the DB and return a common pattern.  But for an object like `Site`, there may be 20 properties.  However, we don't always want to display all 20.  One use case may only need 2.  Another might need 15.  Etc.  Oh, and yeah, Jsonator just popped into my head.  lol

Comment: @DavidGrant Real example provided.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use [`#getDeclaredFields()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields%28%29) to include private fields, [`#getFields()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getFields%28%29) only lists the public ones.

With `private` fields you will also run into access restriction problems, so you probably want to look into the [`Field#setAccessible()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#setAccessible%28boolean%29) method as well.

Comment: Nice catch keppil. Private variables can be accessed once the field.accessible sets to true....

Comment: I'm awarding the anser to @Keppil because it was both the getDeclaredFields and setAccessible that allowed me to do what I need.  Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of kls.getfields you could need to use kls.getDeclaredFields() . And if Jason object is your concern I had recommend you a Jackson Codhaus library . In which you can get or set JsonString from your POJO... HTH

Comment: Correct, I looked at Jackson.  But for the life of me, I can not find a simple to follow tutorial that does what I'm trying to do.  If you have links, that would be appreciated.  I went back to SimpleJSON because it was, well, simple.  :-)

Comment: Here is the simple tutorial I found . HTH http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/

Comment: Thanks, but I found that tutorial too.  What it doesn't tell me is how do I selectively choose properties to output.

Comment: Well I guess I must admit to your solution at this point but still I remember that we can get json string from the map using Jackson lib. Still you said selective property so I guess you need to get Json from your pojo obj only. I could probably do the same using reflection.